# Вектора разных размеров в Matlab записать в одну матрицу с использованием цикла

Tags: массивы, vector, matlab

Есть код, например :

```
U = sin(0.3*(1:500));
n = length(U);
for t = 1:length(U)
       Q = U(t+1:n); 
end
```

Размер вектора U меняется с каждым *i*.
выполнять операции над каждым вектором в цикле я могу, например:

```
for t = 1:length(U)
       Q = U(t+1:n); 
       S (t) = sum(Q);
end
```

Однако у меня возникает необходимость записать каждый вектор в матрицу или извлечь, для дальнейших операций над ним. Если в матрицу записать "Лишние " элементы можно дополнить нулями, например

```
[1 0 0 0 0;
 1 2 0 0 0;
 1 2 3 0 0 ;
  . . . . ]
```

Кто может подсказать как извлечь или записать в матрицу. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Записать в матрицу можно так:

```
M=[]; % В начале матрица пустая
for t = 1:length(U)
    Q = U(t+1:n); 
    M(t,1:length(Q)) = Q;
end
```

Строка `M(t,1:length(Q)) = Q;` означает, что в строку `t` и столбцы с первого по `length(Q)` надо записать строку `Q`. Извлечь можно аналогично:

```
Q = M(t,1:dl);
```

где `dl` - длина извлекаемой части строки. Если нужно извлечь всю строку, то можно так:

```
Q = M(t,:);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!! Я три дня пытался сделать именно так,  единственное к чему пришел это  через cell, а потом в матрицу перезаписать, но это как- то " криво" мне показалось и я стараюсь избегать cell{}, так как при больших массивах  занимают много памяти и возникают дополнительные трудности. Выручили , спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, с векторами разных размеров лучше работать, записав их в массив ячеек. Но раз вам это не подходит, то можно дополнить матрицу нулями, только, судя по коду, у вас должна получиться верхняя, а не нижняя треугольная матрица.

```
U = sin(0.3*(1:500));
Q=triu(repmat(U(2:end),length(U)-1,1));
S=sum(Q,2);
```

Кстати, почему вы решили, что массив ячеек занимает больше памяти? Я тут проверил, массив ячеек занимает меньше места, чем получившаяся верхняя треугольная матрица. Поэтому привожу ещё код с массивом ячеек:

```
U = sin(0.3*(1:500));
n=length(U);
QC=arrayfun(@(x)U(x:n),2:n,'UniformOutput',false);
S=cellfun(@sum,QC);
```

Можете потом выполнить команды `whos Q` и `whos QC`, посмотреть, сколько байт занимают эти массивы, и убедиться, что массив ячеек занимает меньше памяти.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий и примеры кода!

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий и примеры кода!
 Отвечая на Ваш вопрос "Кстати, почему вы решили, что массив ячеек занимает больше памяти?" могу сказать следующее: 
Когда я решал задачи связанные с обработкой изображений, мне нужно было "скользить" по изображению и работать с каждым фрагментом отдельно и я записывал его в массив ячеек и получал ошибку "Out of Memory". В итоге "выкручивался" многомерными массивами или как-то иначе, уже не помню. С тех пор я избегаю ячейки))) Я знаю о командах whos и whos, возможно проблема была в версии Matlab ... или в моем железе.